# How to make this burger button on navbar disappear when I'm on large screen device?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I have this navigation. I intend to make this burger only appear when screen size is below 768px or something. Instead, it keep appear no matter how big the screen size is. Btw, I'm using bootstrap 4.

What I want is, a responsive navbar. So that Home, About, etc link are there when screen are above 768px, not when we click the burger button.

Here's my code.

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar nav-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"
          ><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo.png"
        /></a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarNav"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

By the way, thanks everyone!

Comment: Mabye just use the templates provided in the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Make The Button Disappear You Can Use **@media** Syntax

```css
@media(min-width:768px)
{
  .navbar-toggler{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```